# Store data in NSMutable Array on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I want to store data in key value pair in `NSMutableDictionary` and Store that dictionary in `NSArray` on everytime the button clicks.

**Problem - New data replaces the old one in that array**

*Code -*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _filledDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    _addedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

- (IBAction)addMoreClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

   NSString *availableTo = [to stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@""];

   NSString *from = [[_tfDateFrom.text stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:_tfTimeFrom.text];

  [_filledDict setObject:availableFrom forKey:@"fromDate"];
  [_filledDict setObject:availableTo forKey:@"toDate"];

  [_addedArray addObject:_filledDict]; 

  _tfDateFrom.text = @"";
  _tfDateTo.text = @"";
  _tfTimeFrom.text = @"";
  _tfTimeTo.text = @"";

}
```

*Result I am getting -*

```
<__NSArrayM 0x60000045d6d0>(
{
    fromDate = "2018-08-10 11:16:37";
    toDate = "2018-08-10 11:16:39";
},
{
    fromDate = "2018-08-10 11:16:37";
    toDate = "2018-08-10 11:16:39";
}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `NSMutableDictionary` and `NSMutableArray` is reference type, so when you update the data of `_filledDict`, it will update in the object, that you added to `NSMutableArray` too.

You can simple change `_filledDict` to the function's scope variable to fix it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Remove it
    // _filledDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    _addedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}

- (IBAction)addMoreClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

  // Change to
  NSMutableDictionary *filledDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [filledDict setObject:availableFrom forKey:@"fromDate"];
  [filledDict setObject:availableTo forKey:@"toDate"];

  [_addedArray addObject:filledDict]; 

}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your help..it just made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing dicionary every time so it happens. Please find the below code.

```
  - (IBAction)addMoreClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

   NSString *availableTo = [to stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@""];

   NSString *from = [[_tfDateFrom.text stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:_tfTimeFrom.text];
  _filledDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [_filledDict setObject:availableFrom forKey:@"fromDate"];
  [_filledDict setObject:availableTo forKey:@"toDate"];

  [_addedArray addObject:_filledDict]; 

  _tfDateFrom.text = @"";
  _tfDateTo.text = @"";
  _tfTimeFrom.text = @"";
  _tfTimeTo.text = @"";

}
```

Comment: Great...then please upvote and accept an answer which can help to others.